# Предложите варианты улучшения кода Java

Tags: java

[image]

> Appl класс использует объекты класса Square. Приминить технику
>   "инкапсуляции полей" к полям в Square класса и измените существующий
>   код. Пожалуйста предложите другие решения для улучшения качества кода

Такая задача мне попалось на собеседовании
Такой код может удовлетворить интервьюера?

```html
public class Square {
    private double x, y;
    private double width;

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(double width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public Square() {
    }

    public Square(double x, double y, double width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getPerimetr() {
        return 4*width;
    }
}



public class Appl {
    public void work() {
        Square square = new Square();
        square.setX(2);
        square.setY(3);
    }
}
```

Comment: и что вам нужно?

Comment: Написать код в котором вы инкапсулируeте поля класса Square и предложите еще какие-то изменения для улучшения кода

Comment: так и напишите код, в котором инкапсулируете поля класса

Comment: напишите сначала вашу попытку, тогда мы сможем помочь, просто сейчас это выглядит как учебное задание

Comment: И код надо не картинками а буквами

Comment: Примерно так сделал

Comment: мне кажется псотавленная задача выполнена полностью

Comment: Инкапсуляция в данном случае  - добавление модификаторов доступа private. Вопрос в том, как обеспечить доступ к этим переменным, ведь есть еще модификатор final. Это предпочтительней практически всегда. В этом случае инициализацию предоставить конструктору, а еще лучше билдеру. Ведь по условию задачи не сказано, что после инициализации есть необходимость менять поля. К тому же в исключительных случаях всегда можно создать новый объект.  А заодно можно и намекнуть на знание порождающих паттернов. А еще можно создавать объект через статический метод интерфейса. Подумайте над этим.

Answer (score 0):

Геттеры и Сеттеры не дают автоматически инкапсуляции. Хотя почему-то многие так считают. Скорее даже наличие сеттеров говорит о отсутствии инкапсуляции. И по дефолту надо делать неизменяемые объекты. Мутабельные надо делать лишь при конкретной необходимости (но лучше и в этом случае еще раз подумать). И вообще, геттеры и сеттеры - это не обязанность, а только спецификация по JavaBeans. Ее совсем не обязательно всюду запихивать где надо и не надо.
Вот как можно написать проще:

```
public class Square {
    private final double x, y;
    private final double width;

    public Square(double x, double y, double width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double x() {
        return x;
    }

    public double y() {
        return y;
    }

    public double width() {
        return width;
    }

    public double perimetr() {
        return 4*width;
    }
} 

public class Appl {
    public void work() {
        Square square = new Square(2, 3, 42);
    }
}
```